# Are companion names in SWTOR considered spoilers?

Tags: discussion, site-policies, spoilers

Are the names of companions in SWTOR considered spoilers? You don't find out the info until you reach a specific planet in the story, but you can also see the name of every single one in the Legacy achievements without playing through the story.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, you encounter someone in the story at a point where it wouldn't make sense for them to become your companion, but a twist at some point makes it happen.  You could consider that a spoiler, but it's up to you.  I don't think it's nearly severe enough for anyone to complain about it if you don't use the spoiler markup to hide names.

Comment: Especially as the game has been out for several years, and all that info is easily available.